# Is this an invalid action value in a HTML form?

Tags: html, wordpress, form-submit

I have a HTML form which has the following line:

```
<form action="/?s=test+keywords" method="get">
```

As you can see, I'm sending the form to the URI "/?s=test+keywords".

I know this is a bit weird, but is this an invalid URI or in theory should this work fine?

Currently it's not working for me (the page which loads is "/?"), but I'm having trouble figuring out why. (I'm using Wordpress, so it's possible Wordpress is rewriting this URI.)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a valid (relative) URI but since you have a GET form, the query string is replaced with a new one generated from the form data.

If you want to include some fixed data in such a form then use a hidden input and set the URI to just `/`.

Since you don't seem to be sending any user supplied data at all, you should almost certainly be using a link instead of a form.

Comment: Thank you. Your comment made me realise I never tried using POST instead of GET, and that worked fine. Thanks for your assistance.